# How to Clean Engine Block Surface For MLS Gaskets?

Tags: head-gasket, gasket

**Car: 2010 Passat CC 1.8 TSI**

There is no problem with the old gasket there is no leak i just remove the head because timing problem.

Cylinder head, i've cleaned the head with plastic tools and some cleaning materials looks fine i've checked and tested everything looks good.

[image: Cylinder Head]

Engine Block, i've cleaned the Block using razor blades and plastic tools now there is no gasket material and and the Block surface very smooth but not shiny (please see pics) there is nothing more can do using plastic tools!

How and what is the best way to clean the block for MLS Gasket?

[image: Block surface]

[image: Block surface]

Comment: The best test I've found to tell if the surface is clean enough is to lightly run your fingernail over the surface where you think there may be stuff left. If you feel *any* drag at all, you still have work to do.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 i've tried fingernail over the surface feel so smooth but the block not shiny you can see the pics

Comment: You can buy die grinder disks that have little plastic nubs on them, meant for cleaning aluminum without damaging the surface. Another option is to have it machined by a specialist,

Comment: @Ben machined is not an option, and i think grinder discs bad for mls gaskets.

Comment: This is the style of disc I'm talking about https://www.amazon.com/Scotch-Brite-07528-Quick-Change-Attachment-Aluminum/dp/B000FW4LDU

Comment: @Ben the bad thing that bristle disc is not available locally

Answer (score 1):

As long as there are no nicks or burs on the block you are good to reassemble, clean with brake cleaner and red scotch bright.

Aluminum head should be as smooth as possible to allow sliding on the gasket as it will expand faster and farther than cast iron. Clean same as block.